# not able to run sendEmail.js in nodejs, using nodemailer (Error- Configuration property "EMAIL_SMTP" is not defined) -

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

i am trying to send mail using nodemailer and tried differnt hosts services but encountering this error

WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/home/ayeen/manage/proj-ang/server/utils/config
WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
/home/ayeen/manage/proj-mang/server/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:182
throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
^

Error: Configuration property "EMAIL_SMTP" is not defined

i have json file at config which is
default.json

```
{
    "PORT": 5000,
    "URL": "PROJECT-URL",
    "EMAIL_SMTP": {
        "HOST": "smtp.elasticemail.com",
        "AUTH": {
            "USER": "***ews@ad.com",
            "PASS": "*******"
        },
        "PORT": 252
    },
    "SEND_SMS": {
        "TWILIO_SID": "*********",
        "TWILIO_TOKEN": "********",
        "TWILIO_NUMBER": "+*****"
    },
    "DB_URI": "********"
}
```

and sendEmail.js have this code simpily to send mail

```
import nodelmailer from "nodemailer";
import config from "config"
// import fs from "fs/promises";

const { HOST, AUTH, PORT } = config.get("EMAIL_SMTP");

async function sendMail(emailData) {
    try {
        let transporter = nodelmailer.createTransport({

            host: HOST,
            port: PORT,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user: AUTH["USER"],
                pass: AUTH["PASS"]
            }
        });

        let info = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: `"AD sol" <${AUTH["USER"]}>`,
            subject: emailData.subject, // Subject line
            to: emailData.to,
            html: emailData.body
        });
        console.log("EMAIL SENT");
//         await fs.appendFile("logs/emaillogs.txt", `${info.messageId}
// `);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

// sendMail()
sendMail({
    subject: "User Account Verification - Test",
    to: "ayeen0410gmail.com",
    body: "Testing "
});
export default sendMail;
```

I thought it was host error and tried differnt host services but encounterd same error.

Comment: Can you show the content of the "config" module?

Comment: config has default.json  (config/default.json) 
    {
    "PORT": 5000,
    "URL": "PROJECT-URL",
    "EMAIL_SMTP": {
        "HOST": "smtp.elasticemail.com",
        "AUTH": {
            "USER": "***ews@ad.com",
            "PASS": "*******"
        },
        "PORT": 252
    },
    "SEND_SMS": {
        "TWILIO_SID": "*********",
        "TWILIO_TOKEN": "********",
        "TWILIO_NUMBER": "+*****"
    },
    "DB_URI": "********"
}

Comment: If you're importing "config", you're not importing "default.json"